# How can I make it loop properly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

It won't work when trying to loop so it can restart at the end when asked.

```
def inputPass(message):
  while True:
    try:
       userInput = int(input(message))
    except ValueError:
       print("Not an integer! Try again.")
       continue
    else:
       return userInput

def inputDefer(message):
  while True:
    try:
       userInput = int(input(message))
    except ValueError:
       print("Not an integer! Try again.")
       continue
    else:
       return userInput

def inputFail(message):
  while True:
    try:
       userInput = int(input(message))
    except ValueError:
       print("Not an integer! Try again.")
       continue
    else:
       return userInput

Pass = inputPass("Enter how many passes you got")
if((Pass) != 0 and (Pass != 20) and (Pass != 40) and (Pass != 60) and (Pass != 80) and (Pass != 100) and ( Pass != 120)):
        print("Out of range")
        exit()
Defer = inputDefer("Enter how many defers you got")
if ((Defer != 0) and (Defer != 20) and (Defer != 40) and (Defer != 60) and (Defer != 80) and (Defer != 100) and (Defer != 120)):
        print("out of range")
        exit()
Fail = inputFail("Enter how many fails you got")
if ((Fail != 0) and (Fail != 20) and (Fail != 40) and (Fail != 60) and (Fail != 80) and (Fail != 100) and (Fail != 120)):
        print("out of range")
        exit()

PDF = (Pass + Defer + Fail)

if PDF != 120:
    print("Total incorrect")
    exit()

if Pass == 120:
    print ("Progress")
elif Pass == 100:
    print("Progress (module trailer)")
elif Fail >= 80:
    print("Exclude")
else:
    print("Do not progress – module retriever")
```

I tried using a `while` loop and a function so I can recall back to it but it won't do so and I don't know why.

Comment: You're being very vague. What are you trying to accomplish and what have you done to try to accomodate?

Comment: Aside: Why have you defined separate `inputPass`, `inputDefer`, and `inputFail` functions with identical bodies? Functions are so you don't have to do that. Just define _one_ function and call it three times.

Comment: @TheChicken4452: There's no harm in having it in an `else` block attached to the `try`/`except`; it's not the code they want to catch exceptions from, so it's fine to put it outside the `try` block. The code would be shorter if they put it in the `try`, but it hardly matters; it will work identically either way.

Answer (score 1):

Its kind of difficult to answer since your question is very unclear. You have a lot of repeated code which can be tided up. If the code below doesnt answer your question hopefully it puts you on the right track to solve your problem. If your still struggling please update the question with more clear details.

```py
VAL_RANGES = [0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100, 120]


def get_input(result: str) -> int:
    while True:
        try:
            val = int(input(f"Enter how many {result} you got? {VAL_RANGES}:"))
            if val in VAL_RANGES:
                return val
            print("out of range")
        except ValueError:
            print("Not an integer! Try again.")


while True:
    Pass = get_input("passes")
    Defer = get_input("defers")
    Fail = get_input("fails")
    PDF = Pass + Defer + Fail

    if Pass == 120:
        print("Progress")
    elif Pass == 100:
        print("Progress (module trailer)")
    elif Fail >= 80:
        print("Exclude")
    else:
        print("Do not progress – module retriever")

    if input("Finished? (Y/N):").upper() == "Y":
        break
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Enter how many passes you got? [0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100, 120]:5
out of range
Enter how many passes you got? [0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100, 120]:120
Enter how many defers you got? [0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100, 120]:40
Enter how many fails you got? [0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100, 120]:20
Progress
Finished? (Y/N):n
Enter how many passes you got? [0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100, 120]:120
Enter how many defers you got? [0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100, 120]:0
Enter how many fails you got? [0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100, 120]:0
Progress
Finished? (Y/N):y

Process finished with exit code 0
```